# How many haunts or traitors will there be in a game?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

1. How many haunts can happen per game?
2. Can there be multiple traitors?

I don't understand if the Haunt starts and you can still explore the house what happens if you land on an Omen card

Comment: Your questions are directly answered by the rules, but regardless, they are two distinct and separate things to ask about. Please remove one to its own question. While at it, you should also make the title *much less vague!*

Answer (score 4):

From the rules, p10:

> If the room has an omen symbol, ... **if the haunt has not yet begun**, you must make a haunt roll.

Thus there is only one haunt per game - once it begins you can still draw Omen cards but you do not make further haunt rolls.

With exactly one haunt per game, you will usually find that you also have exactly one traitor per game, though certain haunts are exceptions:

> For example, some haunts have no traitor, and some start with one traitor but have a mechanism to convert more players into traitors over time.

Answer (score 3):

Only one haunt happens per game, and thus there is (usually) only one traitor per game (some specific haunts have a different number).

The [rules](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/HOTH_Rules.zip) state:

> Before the haunt starts, you must roll 6 dice at the end of
>   your turn each time you draw an omen card.

Since it only specifies you roll the dice *'Before the haunt starts'* you would not roll any dice after the haunt starts. The text on Omen card telling you to make a haunt roll is more of a reminder that you need to do that (unless the haunt has started).

Answer (score 2):

> *How many haunts can happen per game?*

One.

> **Before the haunt starts**, you must roll 6 dice at the end of your turn each time you draw an omen card. This is called a haunt roll.

(Emphasis mine)

You only make haunt rolls before the haunt starts. Once a haunt has started, no more haunt rolls are made, so new new haunt is possible. You still draw the Omen cards as normal, though.

---

> *Can there be multiple traitors?*

Yes, but not initially. All but two haunts starts with one traitor, while the remaining two start with none.

In some scenarios, it's possible for heroes to become traitors after the haunt has started. This happens in circumstances defined by the haunt. In at least one scenario, it's possible for every player to become a traitor (leading to the inevitable victory of the haunt).